# embedding a .wav file shows a media player bar I don't want

Tags: jquery, html

Within my jQuery functions I call this line.

```
 $(this).append('<embed src = "Click2.wav"></embed>');
```

This code fires and plays a simple click sound as desired, my problem is, it also displays a small media player bar that I simply don't want. I have tried to look for some options that will hide it including trying to position it off the page but so far to no avail.

I can call `$('embed').remove();` in a subsequent function to get rid of it but my preference is to not show it in the first place.  When I call the remove as a later line within the same function the click does not play.

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On embed element you can use `hidden=true` to answer your first question

Comment: I tried googling for embed options and couldn't find a list, my google-fu is apparently weak.  This solves it perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: If this is the solution you are looking for then please mark this as answered